# iOS Simulator unable to get connection over ethernet

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I've previously bought a MacPro which come with ethernet port and also wifi adapter. I've my wifi turned off and the ethernet port connected with an intranet network cable.

However in my simulator, it keeps showing the error of having NO connection (my Mac can connect to intranet resources perfectly). Fyi, I also noticed that my Mac connection icon was a empty wifi icon, which it means I don't have connection? I just wan my Mac to default to ethernet connection, and my iOS simulator should be able to connect to intranet as expected.

Any help please?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no special setting, Turn Off Wi-Fi and iOS simulator will default to the ethernet connection if active. Check by opening safari in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

iOS simulator uses the same network interface what your MAC is supporting at present.
"I also noticed that my Mac connection icon was a empty wifi icon" It means Wifi is turned off… It doesn't mean that you don't have connection.
Let me know if more info needed.. :)